# VIsual Studio 2017 shared items project not working

Tags: project, shared, items

I have spent several hours trying to get this working with no luck. Adding a reference to a shared items project in VS2017 does not compile properly. It seems like the source files do not compile so I end up with a bunch of unresolved externals.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of QT visual studio tools, I dropped the whole thing and made a CMake project instead. Everything worked flawless after that.